# Indenting answer paragraph after question number

Tags: indentation, overleaf

I'm using LaTeX for my homework for the first time (using Overleaf), and I've run into this problem which I can't solve. I want to indent my answer (for aesthetics), but I also need to specify the question number. So I want a number, and then an indented block of text. This was my solution:

```
\question{1.}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{}
text
\end{adjustwidth}
```

However, this creates a blank line after the '1.' which is impossible to remove.

Comment: Please always provide a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that can be compiled as is. I don't know where the `\question` command comes from, and don't want to guess. You might also want to add an image showing how you want it to look. (Make it in a word processor or whatever if necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlist[enumerate]{left=2em}

\begin{document}
Normal text.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \Blindtext[2]
\item[5.] \Blindtext[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
% indentparabrob.tex  SE 647871

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hangfrom}[1]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}%
  \hangindent \wd\@tempboxa
  \noindent\box\@tempboxa}
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}

  \hangfrom{Question 1 } \newline
  Some answer text following the question number.
  More answer text following the question number.

  \end{document}
```

[image]

The `\hangfrom{<text>}` macro introduces a paragraph where `text` is on the first line and subsequent lines are indented by the width of `text`.

For more information see "TUGboat 28:2 2007" https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf